# asp.net / c# sql connection between multiple users

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session

I have a question bothering me for a while.

i am writing an asp.net / c# application.

i have made the connection string to the database, as a session state variable. That means that each user needs to open only one connection to the db, and from this point i'm using session["dbConn"] to reach the db connection.

the problem is (obviously) the session timeout / "connection property has not been initialized", what should i do? should i open a new connection regardless to the session?

cheers

Comment: show some code what you tried?? where is error ??

Comment: Don' store the connection in a session, close it as soon as possible, best by using the `using`-statement. Opening/closing it does _not_ mean that a new physical connection gets opened/closed at all. Actually due to connection-pooling it's the best way to ensure that only few connections are used. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but unless there is a *very* good reason, this is a terrible design, and does not scale. It would be far more normal to release connections as soon as possible. Normally, this means just "back to the pool", so that another request wanting a connection can use it.

Comment: You mean you're holding the connection open for the entire session (or until it times out)? Connections should be opened and closed as quickly as possible, only when needed.